# What "Top 9 List" Am I?

Tags: riddle

The answer to this riddle is a "Top 9 List" and you have to figure out which one. For example, it could be the top 9 longest rivers in the world, or the top 9 largest non-extinct land animals, etc.

Each of the nine lines below hints at one object. They are actual objects (not concepts or ideas).

The riddle is very literal.

---

My first is part of most tsunamis.
My second is scattered in mastodon remains.
A venomous snake hides my third.
You see my fourth in a jumpy biter.
Maulers and smashers show my fifth.
An imperfect fury reveals my sixth.
A vile spiritualist divulges my seventh.
My eighth is spotted in Pithecanthropus fossils.
Oxygen desaturation tells you my ninth.

---

**Together, in the specified order, what "Top 9 List" am I?**

Comment: The worst destructions ever???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cool, I like it. 
I believe the list is:

> Space Objects listed in apparent brightness in the sky order. 
>  **SUN** : My first is part of most t**sun**amis.
>  
>  **MOON** : My second is scattered in **m**ast**o**d**on** remains.
>  **VENUS** : A **ven**omo**us** snake hides my third.
>  **JUPITER** : You see my fourth in a **ju**m**p**y b**iter**.
>  **MARS** : **Ma**ule**rs** and s**ma**she**rs** show my fifth.
>  **MERCURY** : An i**m**p**er**fe**c**t f**ury** reveals my sixth.
>  **SIRIUS** : A vile **s**p**iri**t**u**ali**s**t divulges my seventh. ( thanks to f'')
>  **CANOPUS** : My eighth is spotted in Pithe**can**thr**opus** fossils.  (thanks to f'')
>  **SATURN** : Oxygen de**satur**atio**n** tells you my ninth.

Comment: not quite. on the right general track, but what about those other 2 lines?

Comment: I am working dude got one more.

Comment: I think it's just all celestial objects in order of brightness. The seventh is Sirius and the eighth is Canopus.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

The list is

> Programming language

My first is part of most tsunamis.

> C (sea)

My second is scattered in mastodon remains.
A venomous snake hides my third.

> Python

You see my fourth in a jumpy biter.

Maulers and smashers show my fifth.

> Bash (not sure, got this [here](http://dotd.wikia.com/wiki/Mauler's_Smasher) )

An imperfect fury reveals my sixth.

A vile spiritualist divulges my seventh.

My eighth is spotted in Pithecanthropus fossils.

> Java (Pithecanthropus is the Java Man)

Oxygen desaturation tells you my ninth.

Comment: that's crazy that there are that many programming languages in there! totally coincidence. it's a Top 9 List, but does a Top... List exist for programming languages?

Comment: Crap ! It explains the hard time to find the others !

Comment: @jlee Well, you got lists for the most used

Comment: Yeah I guess you do. Good point. Fun fact: Most (All?) Pythons are non-venomous. They are strictly constrictors.